# Querying Google for lat/lon takes a long time, makes UIViewController take forever to load

Tags: objective-c, ios, mkmapview, xcode4.3

I am querying Google for lat/long points for a map view. This can take a long time depending on how many addresses the user has put into the app, as the map views all of them. I also introduced a short delay between querying in the `for` loop to make sure that Google gives me good results (if you query too quickly it doesn't give you valid lat/long points but 0,0).

Because this takes so long, once the user presses the button to go to this `UIViewController` it takes a long time and I'm afraid the user will think the app is broken. I would ideally like the ViewController to "show up" but have an map (without annotations initially) with an animated activity indicator over the map until it's finished querying, and then load the annotations. That way the user can look at the other information on the view while waiting for the map to load.

Here is my code:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
    [mapScroll startAnimating]; // activity indicator outlet
    [self makeMap];
    // ... etc.
}

- (void)makeMap {
allRegions = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[self getDistinctRegions]; //generates allRegions array

double maxLat = -90;
double maxLon = -180;
double minLat = 90;
double minLon = 180;

for (int i=0; i<[allRegions count]; i++) {
    NSString *tempString = [allRegions objectAtIndex:i];
    NSString *searchString = [tempString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];
    NSString *queryURL = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?output=csv&q=%@",searchString];
    NSString *queryResults = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:queryURL] encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    NSArray *queryData = [queryResults componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

    if ([queryData count] == 4) {
        double latitude = [[queryData objectAtIndex:2] doubleValue];
        double longitude = [[queryData objectAtIndex:3] doubleValue];

        if (latitude > maxLat) maxLat = latitude;
        if (latitude < minLat) minLat = latitude;
        if (longitude > maxLon) maxLon = longitude;
        if (longitude < minLon) minLon = longitude;

        CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
        coordinate.latitude = latitude;
        coordinate.longitude = longitude;

        MKPlacemark *marker;
        marker = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:coordinate addressDictionary:nil];
        [mapView addAnnotation:marker];

        NSLog(@"%d",i);

        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.12];
    }
}

MKCoordinateRegion overallRegion;

double latSpan = abs(maxLat - minLat);
double lonSpan = abs(maxLon - minLon);
double avgLatitude = (maxLat+minLat)/2;
double avgLongitude = (maxLon+minLon)/2;

overallRegion.center.latitude = avgLatitude;
overallRegion.center.longitude = avgLongitude;
overallRegion.span.latitudeDelta = latSpan;
overallRegion.span.longitudeDelta = lonSpan;

[mapView setRegion:overallRegion animated:YES];

[mapScroll stopAnimating];
mapScroll.hidden = TRUE;
}
```

Comment: use grand central dispatch to throw it into another thread. should be pretty standard.

Comment: @iBlue - I tried that and then none of the pins show up, so I figured it wasn't the right approach to take.

Comment: GCD is async. You need to handle adding pins and stuff in the completion handler.

Comment: @iBlue - Do you know of any tutorial or link that explains all that stuff? I'm kind of a n00b here. Thx!

Comment: Yes. Check out Stanford's iPhone dev course on iTunesU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um, quick and dirty solution, but here is the general process:

1) when user press Go button, you alloc-init your next view controller

2) assuming you have a method to download your lat/long info and a method to render your pin, in your next view controller's viewDidLoad method, you can do something like:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    ....
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(downloadMapData) withObject:nil];
}

// your download map data method
-(void)downloadMapData
{
    // download data from Google API. I assume you know how to do this part.

    // when done, add map annotation points to map on the main thread
    // interface changes must be done on the main thread
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(addPinToMap)];
}
```

Comment: I tried that and it crashes about 7-8 iterations in my for loop. No actual error message is given in the output log so I'm not sure what the deal is.

Comment: OK it actually gets all the way through my for loop (forgot I only had 8 iterations in my simulator) and then crashes when it gets to `[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(addPins) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];`

Comment: Actually I deleted a commented line of code and now it works fine. Thanks a bunch!